# App-V 5 Package Import to SCCM via PowerShell Manifest Error

Tags: powershell, sccm, appv

I am attempting to automate the import of App-V 5 packages into SCCMv1802 via PowerShell. I am using the suggested Add-CMAppvDeploymentType command, targeting the package manifest file. I get an error message (see below) referring to the package manifest file not containing a valid root node.

I have attempted to use different packages and manifest files to rule out a potential dodgy package, but I've ended up with the same result. Importing the packages manually via the GUI also works ok.

```
Add-CMAppVDeploymentType -ApplicationName $AppName -ContentLocation $ContentLocation -DeploymentType "AppV"
```

Here's the exact error message I get:

> Add-CMAppVDeploymentType : The specified App-V package's manifest file
>   does not contain a valid root node At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-CMAppVDeploymentType -ApplicationName $AppName -ContentLocation $ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-CMAppvDeploymentType], InvalidDataException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.InvalidDataException,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.AppMan.Commands.AddAppvDeploymentTypeCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve come across the solution. It turns out that the Add-CMAppVDeploymentType is deprecated and won’t work with App-V 5 packages. I have instead used the [Add-CMAppv5XDeploymentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/add-cmappv5xdeploymenttype?view=sccm-ps) cmdlet which targets the .appv file instead of the manifest.

```
Add-CMAppv5XDeploymentType -ApplicationName $AppName -ContentLocation $ContentLocation -DeploymentTypeName "Appv5X"
```